# How do I make Unity use UTF-8 and LF characters for new script files?

Tags: unity, c#, file-format

By default, when you make a new script in Unity on Windows, it will use UTF-8 with BOM and CRLF. How do I change this to be regular UTF-8 without BOM, and LF (Unix-style)?